# Website fails on trying to update PHP

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2

I tried to update the version on `PHP` on my `EC2` instance using the following commands:

```
sudo yum remove httpd* php*
sudo yum install httpd24 php7
```

While I was previously able to access the website using the `public DNS`, I'm unable to do so anymore. Is there a way to reverse what I did? Also, is there a different way to get my instance to run `PHP 7`?

(I'm a newbie, please let me know if you need more detail.)

Comment: This was an extremely brazen move on your part. There's no way we can tell you to "DO X" and it will be fixed. Instead, you should've tested this all locally to see if it works first. However, now that you're at the point that you're at, it's going to be time to earn that paycheck.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I was just following the answer here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=465912